# Opposite of View.bringToFront() in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I was wondering if there is some opposite method of `View.bringToFront()`?
When I call `bringToFront()` my whole screen get locked cause i have some problem with overriding the `onMeasure()` method(when I implement `onMeasure`, my custom View doesn't draw itself even it enters `onDraw` method) and my custom View takes up the whole screen ...

I badly need `bringToFront()` but I need to start some animation that lasts for three seconds and by calling `bringToFront()` user input doesn't work anymore.

Can I reset that `bringToFront()`?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that you should probably work on implementing onMeasure correctly instead of trying to work around what bringToFront does to your view.

Comment: I didn't have time cause of the deadline for my project. I solved the problem by bringing the things I need in front when animation starts.

Answer (score 7):

I was also looking for a sendToBack() method. However, this does not exist in the current API.

Answer (score 5):

call bringToFront() on the view you want to get in the front, and then call the invalidate() method on all the view including the view which you want in the front. Repeat same for all the listeners. So when another view's listener will get called, the previous view will get invalidated and will be in background.

Comment: Have a look at this post for more info - http://abhishek347.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/android-development-bringtofront-and-sendtoback-on-view/

Comment: Well, yes, there is bringToFront(), but there isn't bringToBack(). That's crazy! For my project i have up to 1000 ImageViews and i need to "bringToBack()" just one of them... now i have to bring to front the other 999!!? Unluckily, View.setZ() is only available starting from API21.